# Order user Tags by Posts

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

Not a high priority, but I would like to order a [user's Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/users/256431/mark-hurd?tab=tags&sort=votes) by number of Posts (the number on the RHS).

This is useful to help determine where they may have their zero scored accepted answers contributing to Tenacious and Unsung Hero badges, etc. I do note a number of "Similar Questions" asking for other more accurate views for these specific reasons.